# How to know the number of clients connected to each SSID using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, networking, wifi, wireless

Is there any `Linux` command/`Bash` script for wireless clients to know the number of clients connected to each WiFi SSID ? How can I do this in `bash` ?

Comment: I just want a simple command/sequence of commands on how to do this. Please suggest how to do this before closing the question.

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/tour) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Ok, I will ask it there, but can you help in this question ? @Cyrus

Comment: No, I do not use Wi-Fi on a Linux system.

Comment: `airodump-ng` - there are many tutorials on the web how to use it... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, so I will give you several answers to point in different directions.

To get all SSIDs (including all public information) you can use the following ...

```
$ su
# iwlist scan
```

I hope this is what you looking for.

If not, then you maybe want to know how many active connections one service is carring. This is by far more complicated. To check for active connections you will need a port sniffler like `tcpdump` and huge knowlegde.

A more common way would be to access the log files or the protocol of the server, but I think you had not asked if you have the rights to do so.

Comment: I need to know number of clients connected to all the nearby SSIDs.

Comment: Then its tcpdump or logfiles. Maybe there are some other tools like wecz mentioned.

Comment: Can you show how to do it using tcpdump ? @suleiman

Comment: Its quite hard to use and I needed guidance to get it running my self. I wanted to check for connections on my server so some1 gave me this: `tcpdump -vvveni eth0 "ip6 and (ip6[6] == 0x06) and (ip6[53] == 0x02)"` Then I was able to check all ipv6 headers for SYN and ACK flags, before iptables could take effect. But as you can see Its really complicated.

Comment: There are guides outside to  check firewalls. `tcpdump` and `nmap` are good examples. You want to allocate headers to get a number close to the connection count of a service.